# RevealAnimator.mClipView leaking Memory when used as close animation in Fragment#onCreateAnimator

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-animation

My Fragment is opening and closing with Reveal Animation, which causes a memory leak of `RevealAnimator.mClipView` (detected via LeakCanary).

I even passed a `WeakReference` of the view instead of the view itself, but is is still leaking memory?

This is my code:

```
fun getExitAnimator(context: Context, viewReference: WeakReference<View>, revealAnimationSettings: RevealAnimationSettings): AnimatorSet? {
    return if (Utils.isLollipop()) {
        viewReference.get()?.let {
            val animDuration = context.resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime)

            val startRadius = hypot(it.width.toFloat(), it.height.toFloat())

            val circularRevealAnimation = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(it, revealAnimationSettings.centerX, revealAnimationSettings.centerY, startRadius, 0.0f)
            circularRevealAnimation.apply {
                duration = animDuration.toLong()
                interpolator = FastOutSlowInInterpolator()
            }
            AnimatorSet().apply {
                playTogether(circularRevealAnimation, getColorAnimator(it, revealAnimationSettings.endColor, revealAnimationSettings.startColor, animDuration))
            }
        }
    } else null
}
```

And the Animator is called in the Fragments `onCreateAnimator`:

```
override fun onCreateAnimator(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animator? {
    return NewBookEntryFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).revealAnimationSettings?.let {
        AnimationUtils.getExitAnimator(requireContext(), WeakReference(requireView()), it)
    }?.takeIf { !enter }
}
```